# DJango switch between databases

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie in python and in DJango, so please, if you can, explain in details.
I want to use in DJango 3 databases: 
1) For DJango auth, admin etc
2) For local website store
3) For the main database

So, frist of all, in my old project (PHP) i was using two databases:

*Frist Database ( localdatabase ): 
-> This database was running on my webhost and contains some variables for the main database

*Second Database ( the main database): 
-> Contains a lot of tables and rows inside which the localdatabase dosn't.

So i want to make a script that reads the tables in this order:
Auth > Localdatabase > Maindatabase

Ex: 
* Localdatabase have this tables:
->autobrands
->autoparts

- Maindatabase have this tables:
  ->AllAutoBrands
  ->AllAutoParts.

I been trying to connect multiple databases, but i don't get it, why is reading only 2 of them.
The code is reading the auth database and the local database.

I have this code:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db':
    {
        'NAME': 'gws2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    },
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'gws',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    },
    'secondary':{
        'NAME': 'gwsautqe_ocar890',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'UkVP0qdlle9TKP2z',
        'HOST': '46.231.42.12',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['gwsauto.routes.AuthRouter', 'gwsauto.routes.PrimaryReplicaRouter', 'gwsauto.routes.SecondaryReplicaRouter']
```

routes.py

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None

class PrimaryReplicaRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'primary'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'primary'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('primary')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True

class SecondaryReplicaRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'secondary'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'secondary'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('secondary')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

models.py

from django.db import models

```
class CarModels(models.Model):   
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "models"

class CarAuto(models.Model):
    BrandName =   models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "gws_brands"
```

On the current code: GWS_brands is on the local database and "models" is on the main database.
Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOQus.png)

Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make migrations and applied them on individual databases?

Comment: Hmm, i think yea. Should i do it again? Running those commands: 
`python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --database= (foreach database )` ?

Comment: No, If it got succeed without any error. You have to create different app for each database and write models accordingly. Define `route_app_labels ` inside each database router so that is can route to correct database according to the `app_label`. If you still have any doubt please ask

Comment: Can't remember if it went without error. Let's assume it does.

Can you give me one example? Should i go copy-paste class AuthRouter: and rename it for each database ?

Comment: Yes something sort of that. So lets say `CarAuto` model is inside `app1` and `CarModels` is inside `app2` you want the `CarAuto` model to be in `PrimaryReplicaRouter ` and `CarModels` in `SecondaryReplicaRouter `. So copy the `AuthRouter` content in other two routers and change `route_app_labels ={'app1'}` for `PrimaryReplicaRouter ` and `route_app_labels ={'app2'}` for `SecondaryReplicaRouter `. Now do makemigrations and apply them individualy again.

Comment: Ok, now i got something like this:
`class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'app1'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'primary'
        return None
`
After i run makemigrations
[link](https://imgur.com/7erTM29)

And i got this error: "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details."

Comment: are your models in different apps? called `app1` and `app2`. Can you share your project directory structure?

Comment: Sure [link] (https://i.imgur.com/iuI3KoI.png)

Comment: As I said you have to create different app for each database. Currently you have all models in `store` app.

Comment: Ok, i got this. Now looks like this : [link] (https://i.imgur.com/T5GyamR.png)

Comment: No, you created two new projects, delete those. You have to create app not project. You can create new app by running following command in your project directory - `python manage.py startapp your_app_name`. and specify app name in `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py`

Comment: Done [link] (https://imgur.com/C3BLRcI)

Error [link] (https://imgur.com/qeUIfor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `CarModels` inside `app1/models.py` and `CarAuto` inside `app2/models.py`

routers

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

        def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
            if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
                return 'auth_db'
            return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None

class PrimaryReplicaRouter:

    route_app_labels = {'app1'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'primary'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'primary'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('primary', 'secondary')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'primary'
        return None

class SecondaryReplicaRouter:

    route_app_labels = {'app2'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'secondary'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'secondary'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('secondary')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

now run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate --database= (foreach database )`